# Issue With List Email Events and Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am having an issue with EmailReceived method with a custom list.

After creating the event receiver and setting "Handle EmailReceived" = true in the folder properties area of the event item the following is stubbed in the .cs file

```
public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPEmailMessage 
    emailMessage, string receiverData)
    {
      base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
    }
```

I know that SPEmailMessage is contained in Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities, but when I change the parameter in what is stubbed out the "Handle EmailReceived" is automatically changed to false causing my code not to get called.

I have tested using the default email to list item feature on other list types like announcements and everything works fine. However I have the same problem with the wrong parameters being stubbed out on them also.

I have searched everywhere and I can't find anyone else with a similar problem.

The software I am using is VS2010 SP1 and Sharepoint 2010.

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in an incident with Microsoft Support and they concluded that it was a bug and will be fixed in a future update.